# I am trying to develop an android app where I am scanning for nearby bluetooth devices. But when I run it, there are no results

Tags: java, android

I am developing an Android app in Java to scan for nearby Bluetooth devices. All permissions have been given, no errors in the code and yet when I run it, there are no results. The tutorials I followed seem to be old. Can anyone point out what can be done or show me some newer tutorial. Thanks in advance.

```
public class ThirdActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
    private final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
    private final int REQUEST_PERMISSION = 2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.third_activity);

        Button scanButton = findViewById(R.id.scanButton);

        bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        if (bluetoothAdapter == null) {
            // Device does not support Bluetooth
            Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth is not available on this device.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
            return;
        }

        scanButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                checkBluetoothPermission();
            }
        });
    }

    private void checkBluetoothPermission() {
        // Check if BLUETOOTH and BLUETOOTH_CONNECT permissions are granted
        int bluetoothPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH);
        int bluetoothConnectPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT);

        if (bluetoothPermission == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                bluetoothConnectPermission == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Permissions are granted, start scanning
            startBluetoothScan();
        }
        else {
            // Request permissions
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT},
                    REQUEST_PERMISSION
            );
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults); // Call super

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_PERMISSION) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 &&
                    grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                    grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Permissions granted
                startBluetoothScan();
            } else {
                // Permission(s) denied
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission(s) denied. Cannot scan for Bluetooth devices.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        int bluetoothPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH);
        int bluetoothConnectPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT);
        int bluetoothScanPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN);


        if (bluetoothPermission == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                bluetoothConnectPermission == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                bluetoothScanPermission == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Permissions are granted, start scanning
            startBluetoothScan();
        } else {
            // Request permissions
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    this,
                    new String[]{
                            Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH,
                            Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT,
                            Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN
                    },
                    REQUEST_PERMISSION
            );
        }

    }


    private void startBluetoothScan() {
        // Ensure Bluetooth is enabled
        if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                return;
            }
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        }
        else {
            // Bluetooth is enabled, start scanning
            doBluetoothDiscovery();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BT) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                // Bluetooth is enabled, start scan
                doBluetoothDiscovery();
            } else {
                // User canceled enabling Bluetooth
                Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth must be enabled to scan for devices.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    private void doBluetoothDiscovery() {
        // Register a BroadcastReceiver to listen for discovered devices
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);

        // Start discovery
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        if (bluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                return;
            }
            bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        }
        bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
    }

    private final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                // Device found
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(ThirdActivity.this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // TODO: Consider calling
                    //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                    // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                    //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                    //                                          int[] grantResults)
                    // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                    // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                    return;
                }
                String deviceName = device.getName();
                String deviceAddress = device.getAddress();
                // Handle the discovered device, e.g., add it to a list or display it
                System.out.println(deviceName+deviceAddress);
                Toast.makeText(ThirdActivity.this, "Found Bluetooth Device: " + deviceName + " (" + deviceAddress + ")", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        // Unregister the BroadcastReceiver when the activity is destroyed
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    }
}
```

I thought maybe it was a mistake with the way of displaying the results, so i replaced toast with a listview object. But that didn't help either.

Comment: Create BLE simulator and test 

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.github.webbluetoothcg.bletestperipheral

Comment: Which Bluetooth devices do you wan't to scan/discover?  *Bluetooth classic* or *Bluetooth low energy*

Comment: I want to discover BT low energy

Answer (score 0):

1. Try adding permission Bluetooth connect without location `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" android:usesPermissionFlags="neverForLocation" />`
2. If you are trying to search for a beacon, then add Location permissions in Manifest and try turning ON Location.
3. If you are scanning a BLE device you can use BluetoothLeScanner.startScan() method instead.